# Register a Pandas Dataframe with Vector Embeddings to Azure

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, azure, azure-cognitive-search

I have a Pandas dataframe with a vector column, which contains embeddings that are used to load data into a vector index in Azure Cognitive Search.

As these embeddings take hours to generate, I need to save them. So far, the most practical way has been turning the column into strings and saving the dataset as a .CSV file.

However, if I try to register the dataframe with the strings as a dataset on Azure (which is the most useful format for me) I get the following error:

> Error code: ScriptExecution.ReadDataFrame.Unexpected
>
> Error message: ScriptExecutionException was caused by ReadDataFrameException.
> Unexpected exception during ReadDataFrameFromSocket.
> Failed to read DataFrame from host.
> Non-negative number required. (Parameter ‘count’)

I am using `Dataset.Tabular.register_pandas_dataframe()` to register it. If the dataframe does not contain the vectors (as strings) column, I can register it without problems.

Of course, I could create a column per dimension of the vector, copy each value there, register the dataset, and then reformat those columns into a list of floats when I read it, but I imagine there must be a better way to do this. Adding a string prefix to the values (so that Azure just interprets them as strings) produces the same error.

Any advice on how I can register a dataframe with a column containing lists of floats as an Azure dataframe? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you please add a sample of what one row in your csv looks like as a string vs as a list of floats?

Comment: @Robert-MSFT - Absolutely. I had to rename the fields/contents, but it is similar to this: ```field1,field2, field3, field4_str content1, content2, content3, "[0.027414847165346146, -0.013949794694781303, -0.01817782036960125, -0.0018194651929661632, -0.007776067592203617, 0.034685976803302765, -0.002427075756713748, 0.010085323825478554, 0.02410244382917881, ... , -0.008536843582987785 ]"``` This field was created using ```df['field4_str'] = df['field3'].astype(str)``` before saving it as a CSV. My goal is to do the same, if necessary, but registering it as an Azure dataset.

Answer (score 0):

It's seems the error you're encountering seems related to the difficulty of handling a column of lists of floats when using `Dataset.Tabular.register_pandas_dataframe()`.

As a workaround, you can convert the list of floats to a string representation before registering the dataset and then convert it back to a list of floats when reading the data.

```py
import pandas as pd  
from azureml.core import Workspace, Dataset  
  
# Sample dataframe  
data = {  
    'field1': ['content1', 'content2'],  
    'field2': ['content3', 'content4'],  
    'field3': ['content5', 'content6'],  
    'field4_str': [  
        [0.027414847165346146, -0.013949794694781303, -0.01817782036960125],  
        [0.034685976803302765, -0.002427075756713748, 0.010085323825478554]  
    ]  
}  
  
df = pd.DataFrame(data)  
# Convert the lists of floats to strings
df['field4_str'] = df['field4_str'].apply(lambda x: str(x))  
 with a custom delimiter (e.g., "|")  
  
workspace = Workspace.from_config()
  
# Register the Pandas dataframe as an Azure dataset  
dataset = Dataset.Tabular.register_pandas_dataframe(  
    dataframe=df,  
    target=(workspace.get_default_datastore(), 'your_target_path_on_datastore'),  
    name='your_dataset',  
    description='your_dataset_description',  
    tags=None
)
```

With above code snippet, I was able to register the dataset.
[image]

You can convert it back to a list of floats when reading the data:

```py
dataset = Dataset.get_by_name(workspace, name='your_dataset')  
df_loaded = dataset.to_pandas_dataframe()    
# Convert the strings back to lists of floats  
df_loaded['field4_str'] = df_loaded['field4_str'].apply(lambda x: eval(x)) 
print(df_loaded)
```

[image]